# how to get the num of rows of the sql result in python?

Tags: python, sql

I am quite familiar with the php but having troubles using sql in the python.
In php, i used these lines to see if the query gives some result or not.

```
$query="SELECT ID FROM Employee WHERE user='$username' AND pass='$password'"; 

 $query_num_rows= mysql_num_rows($query_run); //returns number of rows
```

Is there such codes in the python? any resources would be appreciated too. i am having a hard time in using sql in python

Answer (score 2):

The cursor has a [rowcount](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor) property:

```
print(cursor.execute('SELECT ID FROM Employee').rowcount)
```

Comment: So long as the cursor in question implements the [DB API](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/), anyway.

Comment: please check my answer below. i get some error :( @BoshWash

Answer (score 0):

```
db= MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","ahmed","practice")
    cursor=db.cursor()

    #checking phase to stop scrapping
    sql = "SELECT short_link FROM Properties WHERE Short_link='link_result'"
    print (cursor.execute(sql).rowcount)
```

i am using these lines and it gives error `AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute 'rowcount'`

Then I used this which always give 0 result (shouldnt give zero since in the database, it should be matched)

```
sql = "SELECT Short_link FROM Properties WHERE Short_link='link_result'"
    print cursor.execute(sql)
    print cursor.rowcount
```

Comment: does it still return 0 if you "SELECT * FROM Properties"?

Comment: also, if you have more questions don't post them as answers, just edit your original question or write a comment